# Inter-process Pipes in Jython 2.1

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to communicate between a child and a parent process that were forked with a pipe. I was able to get it working in a fairly modern version of python (code below). I am struggling to get this to work in Jython 2.1 (I don't have the option to update it).

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time
import sys

print "starting"

r, w = os.pipe()
prcID = os.fork()

if prcID:
   # PARENT PROCESS
   # Set up write pipe
   os.close(r)
   w = os.fdopen(w,'w')

   for i in range(5):
      time.sleep(1)
      print "- " + str(i) + " -"
   print "Parent is about to write"
   w.write("OMG!!!! IT WORKS!!!!!")
   print "Parent is done writing"
   w.close()

   os.waitpid(prcID, 0)
   print "Parent done Waiting!"

else:
   # CHILD PROCESS
   os.close(w)
   r = os.fdopen(r)
   strout = r.read()
   print "Child read: " + strout
   print "Child done"
   sys.exit(0)

#END of PARENT

print "done"
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Java API from Jython: `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec([sys.executable, "child_script.py"])` with `out = PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream())` and later `out.write("a message to child")`?

Comment: I think that might just work! I dont like it, but its all I got...
I was going to upvote your answer because it got me unstuck, but its just a comment! Thanks!